# Incredulidade Debochada

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, pontuação

Quando alguém faz alguma declaração, consciente de que o que está dizendo é realmente verdade, porém sobre um assunto bastante difícil de se acreditar, como eu poderia escrever uma resposta que transpareça essa incredulidade, mas de forma debochada?

Por enquanto, imaginem um fragmento do filme "A Chave Mágica" (The Indian in the Cupboard). Posso não estar transcrevendo exatamente aquilo que foi dito, mas apenas parar ilustrar como eu tenho em mente:

> - Você não pode contar pra ninguém, mas eu coloco meus bonecos de ação no guarda-louças e tranco, quando eu abro eles estão vivos!
>
> - Hmmm.... é mesmo...? <_<

É realmente uma coisa bastante incrível, mas para quem assistiu ao filme sabe que é verdade.

Na primeira frase o Omri conta pro amigo (Patrick, eu acho) a experiência que teve e o amigo concorda meio que questionando mas ainda assim com certo tom de deboche.

Na bem da verdade eu nem tenho muita certeza se a frase em si é interrogativa ou não. às vezes o simples uso das reticências já resolveriam meu problema, mas ainda vale a confirmação.

Comment: Atenção aos falsos-amigos! :) Em português europeu, [deboche](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/deboche) significa «*vivência desregrada, dedicada sobretudo aos prazeres do sexo, da comida e da bebida. = DEVASSIDÃO, LIBERTINAGEM*».

Comment: Falsos amigos? Não entendi

Comment: @BrunoAugusto   "falsos amigos" é o termo que se dá àquelas palavras que são idênticas em duas línguas, mas tem significados diferentes.  Por exemplo: a palavra "gift" significa "presente" em inglês, mas significa "veneno" em alemão.  Aqui no caso do comentário, apesar de a língua ser a mesma, a palavra "deboche"  tem significados diferentes no Brasil e em Portugal.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo

Comment: falsos cognatos

Comment: @AndréLyra - Não. Falsos cognatos são palavras que parecem relacionadas, mas na verdade não são (como o português *haver* e o inglês *have*). Falsos amigos são palavras que tem significados diferentes (às vezes constrangedoramente diferentes) embora sejam muito semelhantes (e com frequência verdadeiros cognatos). Um exemplo é *exquisito* (finíssimo, de excelente qualidade, em castelhano) vs *esquisito* (estranho, desagradável, em português).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que tu já tenhas respondido a tua própria questão. Mas adicionando mais informações, acredito que qualquer expressão irônica ou de deboche (puxa, caramba, ou até um Bah - utilizado no sul do Brasil) possa ser usado nesse caso. Acredito que já que está está debochando, um questionamento no final também dará esse aspecto para a resposta.

Então, a resposta poderia ser:

Puxa! É mesmo?

Caramba? É mesmo?

Bah! Mas é mesmo?

Comment: E se eu não puder inserir tal expressão no início? No caso em particular que estou trabalhando no momento (não o exemplo do filme, claro), o "deboche" nem é tanto pra ironizar e sim para desconversar, mesmo porque quem o faz é uma pessoa extremamente séria e culta que não se dá à esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Eu usuaria o *Mas*, até pelo motivo que neurologicamente (não sei se é a expressão mais correta) ele acaba tirando o foco do que foi dito anteriormente.
Então ficaria assim:


- Mas é mesmo?!

Comment: Você diz como ````Mas é mesmo?````

Comment: Diria isso mesmo:

Mas é mesmo?

Se for mais informal, poderia dizer:

- Fala sério?

Comment: "sim, querido, mamãe entende.", "Ah, tá bom! Agora me fala do...", "Hum.. cada dia a gente se surpreende mais com as coisas, mas qual era mesmo o nome daquele livro

Answer (score 0):

Sim, conforme já foi respondido, a melhor descrição para esse "Hmmm.... é mesmo...?" é **"uma resposta em tom de deboche"**  Contudo, se o objetivo é desonversar e não iniciar uma discussão tola, podemos sugerir as seguintes respostas ditas, obviamente, sem nenhum traço de sarcasmo:

- "entendo"
- "sei, sei"
- "Ah, sei"
- "éé-é?"